# SQL Server : best way to check values before insert to table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working in a company that has software that can connect to a database and push values to a table.

I have a problem that some properties do not insert into the database.

I check regular insert query in the SQL Server Management Studio, and the insert is ok there.

I want to check the values that came from my software company before insert to the table.

Friends, please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You can try [SQL Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler) to capture queries and data being sent to the database

Answer (score 1):

You can use extended events(light weight version of profiler).You may choose filters as per your requirement and in `set session filters screen` you can try scoping to a single database or a table or even some text using like syntax

Below are the steps

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks TheGameiswar, I did what you suggest here but it not working.
The session show me 0 events

Comment: you will have to play around with capture global fields section(like sql statement ,batch starting..) and also add filters and restrict to one database